# Convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

There is a proposition that states the following: Assume $E$ has finite measure. Let {$f_n$} be a sequence of measurable functions that converges pointwise a.e. on $E$ to $f$ and $f$ is finite a.e. on $E$. Then {$f_n$} converges in measure to $f$ on $E$. How do you show that this fails if $E$ has infinite measure?

Comment: By finding a counterexample.

Comment: @cardinal: Do you mean like {$f_n$} = $\chi_{[n,n+1]}$

Comment: @Sachin: Thank you for editing.  I've deleted my no longer relevant comments.  @Whomever: In case anyone is wondering about the close votes, they were from before the question was edited.

Comment: @Sachin: That is a good one.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: How can I give a good explanation though? I guess it is clear that this particular sequence of functions converges uniformly to 0. What should I do about the convergence in measure?

Comment: $\mu(\{x:|f_n(x)| > \epsilon\}) = 1$ for all $\epsilon < 1$. What more do you need?

Comment: No this sequence does *not* converge uniformly to zero. It only converges pointwise. In fact $\Vert f_{n} - 0\Vert_\infty = 1$ for all $n$, while $f_{n}(x) = 0$ for all $n \geq x$ (that's what Jonas had in mind in his answer below). As I explained in my answer to your previous question, uniform convergence *implies* convergence in measure. Cardinal explained why convergence in measure fails.

Comment: @Sachin: It does not converge uniformly to $0$.  As Theo pointed out in an answer to a question you asked a little while ago, uniform convergence would imply convergence in measure.  It does converge pointwise to zero, and it does not converge in measure to 0 for the reason cardinal gave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see that the proposition is not true in general if $E$ does not have finite measure, you just need a counterexample.  My suggestion is to start with $E=\mathbb{R}$, and come up with a sequence of measurable functions $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converging pointwise to $0$, while the measure of the set where $f_n(x)\geq1$ is always infinite.  For instance, if you have $f_n(x)=0$ when $x<n$, then the sequence will converge to $0$ at each point regardless of what $f_n(x)$ is when $x\geq n$.  This gives a lot of freedom for strange counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

We make the comment of **Sachin** clearer.
Choose $E=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $E$. Consider the sequence of measurable functions $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ given by
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & n\leq x\leq n+1, \\
0& \text{ortherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$ 
for all $x\in E$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Then:

- For every $x\in E$ we have $x\notin [n,n+1]$ or $f_n(x)=0$ for sufficiently large $n$ 
  and so $$|f_n(x)-0|=|0-0|=0$$ for sufficiently large $n$. This implies that
  $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)= 0$$ for all $x\in E$.
  Therefore the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is pointwise convergent
  to $f=0$.
- We observe that
  $$
  \left\{x\in E: |f_n(x)-0|\geq \frac{1}{2}\right\}=[n, n+1].
  $$
  and so
  $$
  \mu\left\{x\in E: |f_n(x)-0|\geq \frac{1}{2}\right\}=\mu([n, n+1])=1.
  $$
  Hence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent in measure to $f=0$.